# Fastest way to do subsetting in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `main` that has 400,000 rows and I want to subset it to retrieve 1 or more rows.

As an example here is a data frame which shows the kind of subsetting I am using the `subset` function:

```
main <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 07:44:00 GMT","2015-02-02 09:46:00 GMT")),
                   name= c("bob","george"),
                   value=c(1,522), 
                   id= c(5,2))

subset(main, date == "2015-01-01 07:44:00" & name == "bob" & value == 1)
```

This works but it is slow and I think it is because I am working with a 400k row data frame. Any ideas how to make subsetting faster?

Comment: You can use `[` instead of `subset` to get a more speed or may be `data.table`

Comment: Or `library(dplyr); filter(main, date == "2015-01-01 07:44:00" & name == "bob" & value == 1)` although I haven't benchmarked it

Comment: That's a fairly small task. My guess is that you have limited memory and are probably paging out to virtual memory.

Comment: The slowness isn't illustrated by the example, but if you have repeated values for those variables, a keyed data table would be quite fast, like `setkey(data);data[J("2015-01-01 07:44:00","bob",1)]`

Comment: @Frank can you give any example on this? Do I need to convert to a data.table? Do I set the keys on all the columns?  What is the J() function? How can I use > or < in the criteria?

Comment: @user3022875 Yes, I'm working on an example now.

Comment: @user3022875 you only need to key by the columns of interest (if you have more columns in real life) and yes you need to convert to `data.table`. `J` is a binary join see [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) for a great intro.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using a keyed `data.table`. Here is how to set that up (for a modified example):

```
require(data.table)
mainDT <- data.table(main)
setkey(mainDT,V1,V2,V3)
```

We can now subset based on equality conditions using syntax like

```
mainDT[J("a","A")]
```

or

```
mainDT[J(c("a","b"),"A",1)]
```

which subsets to where `V1 %in% c("a","b")` (equivalent to `V1=="a"|V1=="b"`).

---

Here is a speed comparison:

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  "["       = main[main$V1=="a" & main$V2=="A",],
  "subset"  = subset(main,V1=="a" & V2=="A"),
  "DT[J()]" = mainDT[J("a","A")],
  replications=5
)[,1:6]
```

which gives these results on my computer:

```
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1       [            5    5.96       NA      5.38     0.57
3 DT[J()]            5    0.00       NA      0.00     0.00
2  subset            5    6.93       NA      6.20     0.72
```

So, subsetting with `J` is instant, while the other two methods take several seconds. Subsetting with `J` in this way is limited, however:

- It is for equality conditions only.
- For the simple syntax above, you need to pass arguments in the order of the key. However, you can select where `V1=="a" & V3 == 2` using `mainDT[J("a",unique(V2),2)]` and it's still quite fast.

Everything you can do with a data.frame can also be done with a data.table. For example, `subset(mainDT,V1=="a" & V2=="A")` still works. So there is nothing lost by switching your data.frames to data.tables, generally. You can convert to a data.table in place with `setDT(main)`.

---

Here is the code for the example:

```
n  = 1e7
n3 = 1e3

set.seed(1)
main <- data.frame(
  V1=sample(letters,n,replace=TRUE),
  V2=sample(c(letters,LETTERS),n,replace=TRUE),
  V3=sample(1:n3,n,replace=TRUE),
  V4=rnorm(n))
```

The improvement seen in the benchmark above will vary with your data. When you have many observations (`n`) or few unique values for the keys (e.g., `n3`), the benefit of subsetting with a keyed data.table should be greater.

Comment: thanks for the great response. I added more insight into my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977298/using-data-table-subsettting-for-non-equality  can you take a look?  I want to use data.table but I am not sure if I can use >=, <=, and or operators.