# Using data.table Subsettting for non equality

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable with 400k rows and I am doing subsetting and it is very slow.

Here is an a sample data frame:

```
                 date   name value size car1 car2
1 2015-01-01 07:44:00    bob     1    5    A    D
2 2015-02-02 09:46:00 george   522    2    B    F
```

Now I subset it the slow way using subset():

```
main<- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 07:44:00","2015-02-02 09:46:00"),tz="GMT"),name= c("bob","george"),value=c(1,522), size= c(5,2), car1=c("A","B"), car2=c("D","F"))
main$date
subset(main,    size >1 
       &  value == 522
       &  name == "george" 
       &  date >= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 03:44:00",tz="GMT") &  date >= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 08:44:00",tz="GMT")
       &  (car1 == "F" | car2 == "F")
)

                 date   name value size car1 car2
2 2015-02-02 09:46:00 george   522    2    B    F
```

This works and returns 1 row but it is very slow.

Thanks to some responses on another question using data.table looks to be much faster so I would like to use data.table to do the same thing as above but I have a bunch of questions.

Here is what I so far:

```
   library(data.table)  
 mdt<- as.data.table(main)
 setkey(mdt, date, name, value,size,car1,car2)
  mdt[.(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 03:44:00"),"george", 522,2,"F","F")]
```

This returns:

```
date   name value size car1 car2
1: 2015-01-01 03:44:00 george   522    2   NA    F
```

Here are my questions:

(1) I want to have a criteria where date >= and  date <= but is this possible using data.table? If not any ideas how to make the subsetting faster?

(2)  I want to have a criteria where   (car1 == "F" | car2 == "F") but is this possible? If not any ideas how to make the subsetting faster?

(3) You can see the output of the mdt[] there is a date of 2015-01-01 03:44:00 but this date IS NOT in the original "main" dataframe. What is happening here?

(4) You can see in the output of the mdt[] there is a car1 value of NA when car1 is not NA in the original "main" dataframe. What is happening here?

Thank you.

Comment: For (1), I think the `roll` argument might be helpful with inequalities, but have not learned it yet myself. I'll leave that to eddi or one of the others more knowledgeable than me. You could check out the wiki or the course to learn what's doable, too: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial

Comment: For (2), could you extend your example to cover that application?

Comment: I think you should be more explicit with your `setkey`. You do not need to include every field unless you are using every field. But all of this should be do-able in `data.table` -- I just don't work with dates often. `xmpl <- data.table(v1 = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), v2 = 1:4); xmpl[v1 == "a" & v2 > 1 & v2 < 4];setkey(xmpl, v1);
xmpl["j"]` Notice once you give a value on a keyed data.table, it will return based on what you gave it -- whether that key is in the table or not.

Comment: @ Frank -- I don't know how to extend the data.table syntax for or statements. I was asking if it is possible.

Comment: For (3) and (4), it is designed to do that. Every row of `J` will have at least one row in the output. If there was no match, it will have `NA` for the non-joined columns. To disable this, try `mdt[.(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 03:44:00"),"george", 522,2,"F","F"),nomatch=FALSE]`

Comment: I mean, it might help if your `mdt` included rows that would differentiate `car1=="F"` from `car1=="F"|car2=="F"` (since those subsets are the same).

Comment: @ Frank car1 and car2 and not he same subsets at all. Consider them just genaric categoryX and Category Y

Comment: Okay, I didn't mean that they were subsets; I meant that the conditions given are equivalent to subsets. I think there are two issues in (2). First, those columns are really far into the key, making joining on them rather cumbersome, like `myJ <- with(mdt,CJ(
  unique(date),
  unique(name),
  unique(value),
  unique(size),
  "A"
)); mdt[myJ,nomatch=FALSE]`. A new feature of "secondary keys" may help with that. The second issues is using `|` instead of `&`. I don't know a trick for doing that.

Comment: By "cumbersome", I mean that `myJ` will be enormous for any data of moderate size. I think we've reached the limits of my knowledge, so I'll wait for someone with a deeper understanding to come along and answer :)

Comment: My first reaction is - there is no way that first sentence is true - regular `data.table` subsetting on 400k rows should be instantaneous (as far as your brain/eye/hand coordination are concerned). Please add a reproducible example that shows said "slowness".

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you just put the criteria in the `i` expression.

```
setDT(main)
main[size >1 &
       value == 522 &
       name == "george" &
       date >= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 03:44:00",tz="GMT") &
       date >= as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 08:44:00",tz="GMT") &
       (car1 == "F" | car2 == "F"), ]
```

Result:

```
                  date   name value size car1 car2
1: 2015-02-02 09:46:00 george   522    2    B    F
```

So, is that faster than `subset`? Yup.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1)

cf <- function(n) {
  main <- 
    data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+runif(n, 0, 100)),
               name = sample(c("bob","george"), n, replace=T),
               value = round(runif(n, 400,600), 0), 
               size= sample(1:5, n, replace=T), 
               car1= sample(LETTERS[1:6], n, replace=T), 
               car2= sample(LETTERS[1:6], n, replace=T),
               stringsAsFactors=F)
  mdt <- data.table(main)
  setkey(mdt, date, name, value,size,car1,car2)

  pre <- Sys.time()
  mdt[size > 1 & value > 100  & name == "george" &
         date >= as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) & date <= as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+50) &
         (car1 == "F" | car2 == "F"), ]
  dt_time <- Sys.time() - pre

  pre <- Sys.time()
  subset(main, 
         size > 1 & value > 100 & name == "george" &
         date >= as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) & date <= as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+50) &
         (car1 == "F" | car2 == "F"))
  subset_time <- Sys.time() - pre

  return(c(n=n, dt_time=dt_time, subset_time=subset_time))
}

result <- sapply(10^(2:7), cf)
result <- melt(data.frame(t(result)), id.var='n')

ggplot(result, aes(x=n, y=value, color=variable)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_bw() +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: so you cannot use J expressions (i.e. .() or list()) with >=, <=, &, |, etc...?

Comment: You wanted to subset a data.table using the conditions above, right? `i` is for subsetting rows, not `j`. You can use expressions in `j`, but that's for transforming columns, not subsetting rows

Comment: Fyi, those are not "hardcoded expressions in `j`", since `j` refers to the second argument, like `DT[i,j]`. It gives you what you entered in this special case where nothing in `J` matches. Otherwise, it might give you a mixture of things. Setting `nomatch=FALSE` turns on expected behavior (returning nothing, since there is no match).

Comment: Oh you are right. I saw a comma before the `.` where there isn't actually one. editing

Comment: This answer is correct, but I guess it was implicit in the question that the OP wants something faster than `subset`. I guess this takes about the same time. Also, the speed you see in the OP's example is necessarily instantaneous since it only has two rows :)

Comment: @Frank actually `data.table` sets secondary keys, and I think after the first, run, this code will be almost as fast as a binary join

Comment: Cool, thanks for doing the benchmark @arvi1000 . That's not the result I'd expected

Comment: First time was without `setkey`. Just updated and DT appears to get even a little better still